# Ckeditor 5 does not work when I add plugins (with no errors)

Tags: plugins, ckeditor, paragraph, ckeditor5

```
import InlineEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-inline';
// import Bold from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/bold';

InlineEditor
    .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ), {
        // plugins: [ Bold ],
        toolbar: [ 'bold' ]
    } )
    .then((editor) => {
        editor.setData('Some Text');
    })
    .catch( error => {
        console.error( error );
    } );
```

[image]

When I enable plugins:

```
import InlineEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-inline';
import Bold from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/bold';

InlineEditor
    .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ), {
        plugins: [ Bold ],
        toolbar: [ 'bold' ]
    } )
    .then((editor) => {
        editor.setData('Some Text');
    })
    .catch( error => {
        console.error( error );
    } );
```

[image]

My npm packages

```
webpack-demo@1.0.0 /var/www/english.dev.*******/frontend/web/js/npm/webpack-demo
├── @ckeditor/ckeditor5-autoformat@1.0.0-alpha.2
├── @ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles@1.0.0-alpha.2
├── @ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-inline@1.0.0-alpha.2
├── @ckeditor/ckeditor5-core@1.0.0-alpha.2
├── @ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic@1.0.0-alpha.2
├── @ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine@1.0.0-alpha.2
├── @ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials@1.0.0-alpha.2
├── @ckeditor/ckeditor5-image@1.0.0-alpha.2
├── @ckeditor/ckeditor5-markdown-gfm@1.0.0-alpha.2
├── @ckeditor/ckeditor5-paragraph@1.0.0-alpha.2
├── @ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui@1.0.0-alpha.2
├── @ckeditor/ckeditor5-utils@1.0.0-alpha.2
├── babel-cli@6.26.0
├── babel-core@6.26.0
├── babel-loader@7.1.2
├── babel-plugin-transform-class-properties@6.24.1
├── babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy@1.3.4
├── babel-preset-env@1.6.1
├── babel-preset-react@6.24.1
├── compression-webpack-plugin@1.1.2
├── css-loader@0.28.7
├── fade-props@2.1.0
├── gzip-loader@0.0.1
├── jquery@3.2.1
├── lodash@4.17.4
├── mobx@3.4.1
├── mobx-react@4.3.5
├── node-sass@4.7.2
├── raw-loader@0.5.1
├── react@15.6.2
├── react-addons-css-transition-group@15.6.2
├── react-addons-update@15.6.2
├── react-css-transition-replace@3.0.2
├── react-dom@15.6.2
├── react-redux@5.0.6
├── react-router@4.2.0
├── react-router-dom@4.2.2
├── redux@3.7.2
├── redux-devtools@3.4.1
├── sass-loader@6.0.6
├── style-loader@0.19.1
└── webpack@3.10.0
```

.html

```
<div id="editor"></div>
```

Actually my goal is to insert html with tag , via method setData(), but as I underdtood, I need to use plugin Markdown. But anyway I can't make it work with any plugins. Thank you.

P. S. I tried basic and inline forms but the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that it was because there wasn't imported and used Paragraph

```
import Paragraph from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paragraph/src/paragraph';

....
plugins: [ Paragraph ]
.....
```

I think it's not good behavior for ckeditor. But it is 1.0.0 what do I want from it.. xD

Answer (score 0):

CKEditor 5 is highly modular and even features such as support for typing are separate plugins which you need to load. An editor creator cannot assume which modules should be loaded and leaves all that to the developers.

You can read more about the architecture in ["Architecture overview"](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/overview.html).

So, it's your obligation to load all necessary plugins **when you're building the editor from source**. If you use existing editor builds you [don't have to do that](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/quick-start.html) because builds have a set of plugins built in.

BTW, loading `Paragraph` is not enough to create an editor. You won't be able to type or paste. Therefore, there's a plugin which enables all these essential features – [`Essentials`](https://ckeditor5.github.io/docs/nightly/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_essentials_essentials-Essentials.html).

Refer to the CKEditor 5 Framework's ["Quick start" guide](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/quick-start.html#Let-39-s-start) for more information (e.g. ready-to-use code snippets).

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, I found it out just now before I saw your message :( Could have saved a few hours...

Comment: @reinmar : I  am facing tough time in setting up the copy paste feature or I am not sure how to do it.I want to setup Base64UploadAdapter for image save.kindly provide your inputs. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57090810/pastefromoffice-option-in-classic-ckeditor-5