# PasteFromOffice option in classic ckeditor 5

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I am trying to setup classic ckeditor in my angularjs application. I have installed via npm and classic ckeditor 5 is up.

I am trying to copy paste contents to ckeditor but it is failing with the error saying **filerepository-no-upload-adapter: Upload adapter is not defined.**

**Does this error mean the final classic ck editor build(12.3.1) doesnt have this plugin?**

Below is the code which I am trying.

```
ClassicEditor.create( document.querySelector( '#editor' )
 )
.catch( error => {
console.error( error );
} );


ClassicEditor.builtinPlugins.map( plugin => console.log(plugin.pluginName) );
```

**ClassicEditor.builtinPlugins.map logs** 'alignment','Essentials','CKFinderUploadAdapter','Autoformat','BlockQuote','CKFinder','EasyImage','Image','ImageCaption','ImageStyle','ImageToolbar','ImageUpload','List','MediaEmbed','Paragraph','PasteFromOffice','Table','TableToolbar'

**Does this mean the final classic ck editor build(12.3.1)  have these plugins?**

Answer (score 0):

the [filerepository-no-upload-adapter](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/support/error-codes.html#error-filerepository-no-upload-adapter) means that your editor instance does not have any upload adapter defined. The best way to learn about defining an upload adapter is to follow the [Image upload overview](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/image-upload/image-upload.html)  and either use (thus configure it) one of the official upload adapters or [create a custom upload adapter](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/deep-dive/upload-adapter.html) for your server.

ps.: There's an issue that currently the CKEditor 5 have not [an official plugin for inserting images via a URL](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/issues/229). However, there's a [guide](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/creating-simple-plugin.html#step-4-inserting-a-new-image) for that.